# Switched from Ubuntu to Xubuntu, only the UI has changed not the OS

Tags: xubuntu

I was running on dual boot Ubuntu over Windows 8 and used grub to choose the OS. I decided to switch from Ubuntu to Xubuntu and followed the instructions on  [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111029034409/https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/alternative).

After restarting I checked the version in terminal it's showing Ubuntu and when I lock the system, it shows xscreensaver 5.30. You can observe in the screenshot, it shows two times and a calendar, one in Ubuntu style and one in Xubuntu style and there is power button near the time like Ubuntu. Grub also displays the OS as Ubuntu. How to get rid of this and use pure Xubuntu?

Switched from Ubuntu to Xubuntu, only the UI has changed not the OS:

[image: screenshot of the desktop]

Comment: The only difference is the desktop environment and eventually some DE specific tool/software. You have a fundamental misunderstanding right there but that, however, is not the main problem. You're running an outdated, unsupported release (15.04). Please install a supported release.

Comment: I did not notice the version of ubuntu. @CelticWarrior Thanks for pointing it out. In this case, I would suggest a fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the panel on top and go to panel preferences. You can add or delete the items you want on there. Xubuntu has this panel item called notification manager that is not there in the default xfce desktop. Some of the notifications such as clock and power manager are repeated here. You can either remove these in the notification manager preferences which can be accessed from panel preferences or you can remove the xfce items.

As for the screensaver, Xscreensaver is what ships with the default xfce desktop. I faced the same problem when I switched from kubuntu to xubuntu. I was unable to find a solution and just did a fresh install of xubuntu. Maybe someone else can suggest a solution to this problem.

Comment: I uninstalled xscreensaver and got a new look, thanks for helping me with the panel issue.